# Access html controls from external class

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

To implement a communication channel between an `ASP.NET Website` and a `C# application`, I followed this example:

https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/

In my html I have a `ASP.NET Label`:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="label"></asp:Label>
```

And here is the code behind the page:

```
using Interfaces;
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    static IService service;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var callback = new Callback();
        var context = new InstanceContext(callback);
        var pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IService>(context, new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/ipc"));

        try
        {            
            service = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
            service.Connect();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Server connected!");
        }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Server not found");
        }
    }
}

public class Callback : ICallbackService
{
    public void SendCallbackMessage(string message)
    {
        // label.Text = message;
    }
}
```

When I receive the message from the other application, inside the "Callback" class, I want to access to the "label" control on the web page.

I don't understand how to retrieve the html controls from this external class.

Comment: Nothing besides your page should be accessing the controls. Instead, pass values back and forth as necessary. Don't let your page logic leak into your external services.

Comment: Ok, but how? As you can see from my comments to the first answer, I tried to add a method to pass the value, but it seems it doesn't work. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong!

Comment: Are you stuck with using WCF? What kind of data do you need to pass back and forth?

Comment: I need to exchange strings data, like serialized json objects. I'm not "stuck" but because `WCF` works for me, I'm open to other alternative if they're better and it worth the further changes to the code.

Comment: Well whatever you use, just write code in your code behind to gather necessary data needed by the external application, and send it as part of your message.

Comment: I apologize, but I don't understand your answer. Would you please explain a bit more, writing an answer to show me how to update the control on the page?